# xmlUnlinkNode not removing the Child node from xml file

Tags: c, xml, libxml2, removechild

I am using xmlUnlinkNode and then free to remove a child node from my xml file. Though the code is getting in there to execute, the node is still present in my xml file after processing.

```
xmlDocPtr file = xmlParseFile("text.xml");
xmlNodePtr cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(file); //memory

printf("Name root = %s\n", cur->name);
for(cur=cur->children; cur;) {
printf("Name = %s\n", cur->name);
if(xmlStrEqual(cur->name, "section")) {
    xmlNodePtr node = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
    printf("Deleting!!\n");
    xmlUnlinkNode(node);
    xmlFreeNode(node);
} else {
    cur = cur->next;
}
}
```

My XML file:

```
<memory>
<section>    --> Planning to delete this child node.
<resource>
<core>
</core>
</resource>
</section>
</memory>
```

Run:

```
   ./a.out
   Name root = memory
   Name = text
   Name = section
   Deleting!!
   Name = text
```

Comment: Oops..i was not saving the file at the end.."xmlSaveFormatFile" fixed the issue :)

Comment: [xml manual](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html), says about `xmlUnlinkNode()`: *Unlink a node from it's current context, the node is not freed If one need to free the node, use xmlFreeNode() routine after the unlink to discard it. Note that namespace nodes can't be unlinked as they do not have pointer to their parent.*